# Some fields become invisible after onResume in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have scaffold with some floatingActionButton and bottomBar

And the main views.

On the first layout show, all works fine, but
if you push home button and go back to the application, all fields after bottomBar
become invisible.
Last stop of breakpoint will be on column.

Additionally I have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" flag in my androidmanifest file.
But if you click on this invisible fields, then all logic will work.

Maybe its duo to scrollstate?

```
Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        floatingActionButton = {},
        bottomBar = {}
) { innerPadding ->
  val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column(
       modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .fillMaxHeight()
          .padding(innerPadding)
          .verticalScroll(scrollState),
          horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        ) {
        //after this line all become invisible
        Row(){} //become invisible
   }
 
}
```

Comment: Is the `Row` outside the `Column`? If yes, the issue is due to `.fillMaxHeight()` on the `Column`.

Comment: No, it is inside Column. Column and 3 Rows in it. And it doesn't solve the issue.